# python spambot featureset list size

Tags: python, nlp

novice coder here, trying to sort out issues I've found with a simple spam detection python script from Youtube.

Naive Bayes cannot be applied because the list isn't generating correctly. I know the problem step is

```
featuresets = [(email_features(n),g) for (n,g) in mixedemails]
```

Could someone help me understand why that line is failing to generate anything?

```
def email_features(sent):
    features = {}
    wordtokens = [wordlemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_tokenize(sent)]
    for word in wordtokens:
        if word not in commonwords:
            features[word] = True
    return features

hamtexts=[]
spamtexts=[]

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join('ham/','*.txt')):
text_file =open(infile,"r")
hamtexts.append(text_file.read())
text_file.close()

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join('spam/','*.txt')):
text_file =open(infile,"r")
spamtexts.append(text_file.read())
text_file.close()

mixedemails = ([(email,'spam') for email in spamtexts]+ [(email,'ham') for email in hamtexts])

featuresets = [(email_features(n),g) for (n,g) in mixedemails]
```

Comment: Can you show us a part of the generated list? Is the list completely empty?

Comment: That question led me to something else; I'm taking the size =int(len(featuresets)) and it always comes back as 0

But taking the same length for mixed emails does the same thing

is it not being written as a list?

Answer (score 0):

I converted your problem into a minimal, runnable example:

```
commonwords = []

def lemmatize(word):
    return word

def word_tokenize(text):
    return text.split(" ")

def email_features(sent):
    wordtokens = [lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_tokenize(sent)]
    features = dict((word, True) for word in wordtokens if word not in commonwords)
    return features

hamtexts = ["hello test", "test123 blabla"]
spamtexts = ["buy this", "buy that"]

mixedemails = [(email,'spam') for email in spamtexts] + [(email,'ham') for email in hamtexts]
featuresets = [(email_features(n),g) for (n,g) in mixedemails]

print len(mixedemails), len(featuresets)
```

Executing that example prints `4 4` on the console. Therefore, most of your code seems to work and the exact cause of the error cannot be estimated based on what you posted. I would suggest you to look at the following points for the bug:

1. Maybe your spam and ham files are not read properly (e.g. your path might be wrong). To validate that this is not the case add `print hamtexts, spamtexts` before `mixedemails = ...`. Both variables should contain not-empty lists of strings.
2. Maybe your implementation of `word_tokenize()` returns always an empty list. Add a `print sent, wordtokens` after `wordtokens = [...]` in `email_features()` to make sure that `sent` contains a string and that it gets correctly converted to a list of tokens.
3. Maybe `commonwords` contains every single word from your ham and spam emails. To make sure that this is not the case, add the previous `print sent, wordtokens` before the loop in `email_features()` and a `print features` after the loop. All three variables should (usually) be not empty.

Comment: Okay, I'm able to print the list(featuresets), and there's definitely a list there.

For some reason, len(featuresets) and len(list(featuresets)) are still giving me 0